# C# "System.StackOverflowException:" when assigning event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, stack-overflow

I have an initialization routine called from the Form's Show event.
When the initialization is done, it fires an Initialized event.

In this event I assign the event handlers to the initialized objects. But as soon I try to assign this event, I get "System.StackOverflowException:". I have put a break point in the event to see if it was called recursively, but it isn't.

```
SCD.OCV.OnCard += OCV_OnCard;
```

The event handler in the `SCD.OCV.OnCard` is defined like this in the TOCV class:

```
public class CardEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CardEventArgs(TCard card, ECardStatus status)
    {
        Card = card;
        Status = status;
    }
    public ECardStatus Status { get; }
    public TCard Card         { get; }
}
public             event CardHandler OnCard;
public    delegate void  CardHandler(object sender, CardEventArgs e);
protected virtual  void  FireCard(CardEventArgs e)
{
    OnCard?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

The event handler I try to assign is defined like this:

```
private void OCV_OnCard(object sender, TOCV.CardEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {

    });
}
```

And now to the assignment where all crash:

```
SCD.OCV.OnCard += OCV_OnCard; // Here I get the StackOverflowException
```

C# is not my major programming language (I'm more familiar with C/C++) so I'm not 100% sure if all is done correctly.

**[EDIT]**
Managed to track down the issue. It was a third party C/C++ DLL not terminating a string correctly. Hence a char* went wild in the memory.

Comment: (Unrelated, but use `EventHandler<CardEventArgs>` rather than `CardHandler`)

Comment: If `OnCard` is a field-like event, and `SCD.OCV.OnCard += OCV_OnCard;` throws, I can only assume that either `SCD` or `SCD.OVC` is causing the exception - can we see *that*?

Comment: @dymanoid You can often get a hint by stabbing Break while it's busy getting to the point of overflowing, and the Call Stack window shows useful information.

Comment: This problem seems to be a bit random. Now it worked without exceptions so something is a bit unstable. I agree, it must have something to do with the TOCV object, but only assigning an event handler, what can possible go wrong?!?

Comment: @Max well, I've seen people implement events in a recursive way, i.e. `public event SomeType Foo { add { Foo += value; } remove { Foo -= value; }}` - which would absolutely throw a `StackOverflowException` - but you don't show that in your example. Hence my suspicion that the real problem here is `SCD` or `SCD.OCV`. Can you show where those come from?

Comment: Both objects are mine and I have some more objects initialized exactly the same way before the SCD.OCV object. These event handler are following the exact same concept as for the TOCV object. But I still don't understand how the event assignment can make the object crash? Is thre any code running in my objects when the event gets assigned? I will update by question with some more code.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, The question is updated. It has start to throw the exception again, at the same spot. I tried to remove the objects inside the TOCV class and now I get "Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' " at the same spot.